# How to make an image comply with the circular shape of a wrapping DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm supposed to make a wrapping div circle. In addition, I'm required to use the CSS OVERFLOW property to make the image comply with the circular shape of the div my

I made the div a circle by giving it the same height and width with the border-radius of 50% and an overflow property of hidden. Moreover, I gave the image width of 100% with height auto.

```
  div.profile-pic {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  div.profile-pic img {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: your css is working fine what do you exactly need?

Comment: Yes. But the coding environment(I'm taking a test) I'm writing this code in keeps complaining that the 'div.profile-pic' does not meet the specified style.

Comment: which style do you want?  [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/48o2qzts/3/) or can you show any image reference

Comment: You didn't say what coding environment you're using or what styles it specifies. Are you supposed to make the div circular by another means than border-radius?

Comment: Nothing of that sort was stated as to what method to make the div circular. if you're familiar with how coding task is executed in freecodecamp, that is a similar environment I'm working in.

Comment: @MrLister this is the question: The .profile-pic DIV wrapping the user's IMAGE should have 100px of width and height and styled to display as a circle. You might need to explore the overflow CSS property to make the IMAGE comply with the circular shape of the DIV

Answer (score 0):

You could use `background-image: url();` on the profile-pic div

Comment: An image element is required within the div(wrapper)

Comment: You can give the image tag a border radius too?